# CSS sprite animation white flash on reverse

Tags: css, sprite

I made a simple sprite that is animated using CSS only.

```
@keyframes swordAttack {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: -5305px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

The only problem I am having is that when the animation gets to the end (and reverse playsback) there is a white flash i.e. like a frame is missing.

It is hard to explain unfortunately but it is like:

@ @ @ @ @ x @ @ @ @ @

where the "x" seems like a missing frame or white flash. This is also the point where the animation would reverse and play back untill it reached the first frame. This missing frame/ flaash is weird because I do not have a missing frame.

My sprite is 5305px width and each animation portion is of equal width and exists out of 17 "frames".

I am using this code to run the animation:

```
animation: swordAttack 1s steps(17) normal;
```

Everything is working perfect, except for a "white flash" if that is what I can call it .

Hope someone can tell me what is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in animation. See your animation should start from 0% then 50% all the way up to 100%. But in your solution it's starting point is 100% then 50% all the way up to 100% again, that might be the bug I think.
Change 100% to 0% and then comes 50%  all the way up to 100%

```
@keyframes swordAttack {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: -5305px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, that was typo indeed :) sharp as a knife ;) but it didnt solve the weird "flash" I see in my animation unfortunately

Comment: Well source code could help to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below:

```css
.anim {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-flex;
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYtWt.png);
  background-size:auto 100%; /* make it full height and keep width auto */
  animation: swordAttack 1s steps(16) infinite alternate; /* replace infinite with 2 to get only one ruunning */
}

.anim::before {
  content:"";
  padding-top:80.6%; /* this is based on the ratio of one image, adjust it based on the sprite */
}

@keyframes swordAttack {
    100% {
        background-position: right; /* simply move to right */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim"></div>

<div class="anim" style="width:50px"></div>
```

The above is missing one frame due to how `steps()` work but you can edit like below to get all the frames:

```css
.anim {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-flex;
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYtWt.png);
  background-size:auto 100%; /* make it full height and keep width auto */
  animation: swordAttack 1s steps(17) infinite alternate; /* replace infinite with 2 to get only one ruunning */
}

.anim::before {
  content:"";
  padding-top:80.6%; /* this is based on the ratio of one image, adjust it based on the sprite */
}

@keyframes swordAttack {
    100% {
        background-position: calc(100% + 100%/16) 0; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim"></div>

<div class="anim" style="width:50px"></div>
```

Comment: Oh that is a super nice way to do it, ill give this a try thank you!

Comment: @Mithradantor made an update to my answer